# Calculating the poly vertices based on the result of Connected Component Labeling

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tilemap, grid

I am making a tile based game.

And now I can find all the connected area using the Connected Component Labeling algorithm.

But now the problem I am having is how to calculate the poly vertices of each connected area.

For example:
[image]

As you can see all the YELLOW tiles are of the same AREA and with the help of Connected Component Labeling algorithm I know all the (x, y) info of each tile.

And now I want is the generate a poly vertices array for the YELLOW AREA POLY (clockwise).

[image]

Is there any good algorithm for this ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research I finally find a solution based on this post: [java-merge-adiacent-rectangles-into-a-polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997254/java-merge-adiacent-rectangles-into-a-polygon?rq=1)

Here is my solution process sequence in general:

- Extract all edges from the tiles into a EdgeArray
- Remove all the edges that has a duplicated one in the EdgeArray
  this will leaving only the Edges of the merged poly contour I want
- Connect all edges from head to tail , head to tail ...
- Pick up all the vertices point from the edges

and that's the finally clockwise PolyVerticesArray I want.

[image]

Comment: Suggest you accept (checkmark) your own answer when you re-visit this site, so that this question doesn't keep appearing as unanswered / getting bumped by @Community.